# Finding the inverse of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse-function, diffeomorphism

Let $\Phi: U := (1, \infty) \times (-\pi, \pi) \times (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined as
$$\Phi(r,s,t) = (rt\cos(s), rt\sin(s), \sqrt{r^2-1}).$$

I have determined that $\Phi(U) = \mathbb{R}^3\setminus N$ where $N = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\; |\; x \leq 0,\; y = 0\;, z \leq 0 \}$ and $\det \mathrm{D}\Phi$ is invertible for all $(r,s,t) \in U$.
Now I'm having trouble finding the inverse of $\Phi': U \to \Phi(U)$. We have:
$$rt\cos(s) = x\\
rt\sin(s) = y\\
\sqrt{r^2-1} = z$$
Solving the last equation for $r$ gives us $r = \sqrt{z^2+1}$. Plugging this into the other equations gives $t = \frac{y}{r\sin(s)}$ and $s = \arctan{\frac{y}{x}}$ (assuming $y \neq 0 \neq x$). Now if $x = 0$ we have $s = \pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $t = \pm\frac{y}{r}$. If $x \neq 0$ and $y = 0$, we have $s = 0$ and thus $t = \frac{x}{r}$. Now this function doesn't map $y$ to $(-\pi, \pi)$. I'm thankful for every advice!

Comment: You have solved for $r^2$ in terms of $z^2$, and the first two components of $\Phi$ give us $r^2t^2 = x^2+y^2$.  Since $r,t \gt 0$, it remains only to determine the "angle" $s$.  Since $\tan^{-1}$ has a period of $\pi$, it is better to use the information about $\cos(s),\sin(s)$ directly to locate $s\in (-\pi,+\pi)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\tan^{-1}$? If you mean $\tan^{-1} = \arctan$, then this clearly doesn't have a period of $\pi$.

Comment: Right, I misspoke.  It is $\tan(s)$ which has period $\pi$, and for that reason $\operatorname{arctan}$ doesn't quite do what you want (to determine $s$).

Comment: If you have never seen it before, you may want to read about [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) and modify it to get what you need.